# Any tool to plot a time series (time vs usage) graph?

Tags: graph, process, cpu-usage

I have collected CPU usage for a process for every 0.5 second. Now I want to plot a graph, but I am not able to figure out which tool to use. Using Excel or Libre, I can easily plot the graph however it will be too big (since there are approx 4000 CPU usage records). So is there any online tool available, which would display the graph as I wish ? like I could set to see the graph for every 5 mins or 10 mins of CPU usage etc? Where can I flexibly change the range of X-axis ?

EDIT : [Google Graph](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline) seems to have something, currently I am trying to figure out.

Comment: What do you mean by "too big"? Are you thinking Excel can't hold that much data?

Comment: no the graph would be too big in size when plotted. it would be difficult to quantify and see the usage. Instead if I could somehow change it to CPU usage for every 10 mins would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

These might help you..

[List of Graphics softwares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_information_graphics_software)

[SigmaPlot](http://www.sigmaplot.com/products/sigmaplot/sigmaplot-details.php)